# Is it a bad practice or bad for performance to specify css transition parameters for all elements?

Tags: css, performance, browser, css-transitions

On my website (simple multipage wordpress site), I use the same css transition type for all elements that need transition, e.g. `transition: something .2s ease-in-out 0s`. After writing that same rule for different elements over 50 times, I thought it might be a good idea to instead write

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    transition: none .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

and then only specify `transition-property` for each element that needs to have a transition. Note that in the wildcard declaration I specify `transition-property` as `none`, instead of the default `all`, which should mean that no transitions should apply to all elements.

Now my question is - is this a bad practice, or can it be bad for performance? On my website it seems to work just fine, and give adequate page speed results, but I have a pretty powerful laptop and phone, with latest version of browsers. I'm just not sure how the css engine treats that wildcard transition declaration in terms of computing.

Comment: You can use Virtual Box and create low performance PC and see the result.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is maybe.

Here is the long answer:

So long as you're only using transitions that happen in the paint or composite part of the render lifecycle, you should be okay. Where it starts to get dicey is if you start trying to animate things that are on the style or layout part of the render lifecycle.

Browsers have worked really hard to make sure certain properties are performant in general and have given them the ability to be GPU accelerated. The main properties we're talking about here are:

Composite Layer:

- Transforms (All Types)
- Opacity

Paint Layer:

- Colors

You want to try and make all of your transitions only use these. If you don't you will experience *significant* performance degradation. It is considered best practice to only animate on these properties because of this.

So just remember, if you're going to apply a wildcard selector to transition things, make sure the properties that change across different css classes are using properties that take advantage of the composite/paint part of the render lifecycle.

Me personally: I would continue to specify transitions as needed on a class by class basis, because I wouldn't want to risk this affecting performance on something that doesn't expressly *need* to be animated.

[Here's a really fantastic article (apologies for the medium link)](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108)